# how to find a class name and a txt after ajax get

Tags: jquery, ajax, find

After an Ajax get I want to get all the classes that have the name ".eventtitle.notread" and contain the text "text 4"

This is the HTML code i get

```
     <tbody>
<tr>
    <td class='eventchkbox' width="2%"><input type="checkbox" name="del[]" value="2351446"  /></td>
    <td colspan="2" class='eventtitle notread'>
        <a name="event2351446" style="position:relative;top:-135px;left:-8000px;">&nbsp;</a><a href="/events/page/1/2351446#event2351446">Text 1</a>            </td>
    <td class="eventdate">09-06-2013 21:12:12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class='eventchkbox' width="2%"><input type="checkbox" name="del[]" value="2351440"  /></td>
    <td colspan="2" class='eventtitle '>
        <a name="event2351440" style="position:relative;top:-135px;left:-8000px;">&nbsp;</a><a href="/events/page/1/2351440#event2351440">Text 2</a>            </td>
    <td class="eventdate">09-06-2013 21:11:38</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class='eventchkbox' width="2%"><input type="checkbox" name="del[]" value="2348501"  /></td>
    <td colspan="2" class='eventtitle '>
        <a name="event2348501" style="position:relative;top:-135px;left:-8000px;">&nbsp;</a><a href="/events/page/1/2348501#event2348501">Text 3</a>            </td>
    <td class="eventdate">09-06-2013 19:04:35</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class='eventchkbox' width="2%"><input type="checkbox" name="del[]" value="2348489"  /></td>
    <td colspan="2" class='eventtitle notread'>
        <a name="event2348489" style="position:relative;top:-135px;left:-8000px;">&nbsp;</a><a href="/events/page/1/2348489#event2348489">text 4</a>            </td>
    <td class="eventdate">09-06-2013 19:04:01</td>
</tr>
```

With the following code i get the classes ".eventtitle.notread"

```
       $('body').append('<div id="berichten"; style="position:fixed; top:163px; border: 1px solid gray; background: transparant; z-index: 1000000;"></div>)');

     $.get('/events', function(data) { 
                                var berichten = ""; $(data).find('.eventtitle.notread').each(function() {
              berichten += $(this).html() + "<br>";
              });
     $('#berichten').html(berichten); 

     GM_log(berichten)
      });
```

I tried it with .filter I also tried to change the find is something like `$(data).find(".eventtitle.notread" a.contains('text 4'))` But that is not working.

The combination ".eventtitle.notread" and 'text 4' can occur multiple times on the page I get with ajax. The result will be stored in the div "berichten" en needs to be refreshed every time the get function runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(data).find(".eventtitle.notread" a.contains('text 4'))
```

supposed to be

```
$(data).find(".eventtitle.notread a:contains('text 4')")
```

You seem to be missing the `:` that comes before contains

Comment: Thanks shaddow. The only problem is that isn't a html element. When i replace $(data).find('.eventtitle.notread') with $(data).find(".eventtitle.notread a:contains('text 4')") it changes to plain text